# C/C++ SEH Example build failure

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, seh

I am complete unfamiliar with c/c++. I need to compile a small program to do some analysis.

This is the program

```
  #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>
//#include<seh.h>
#include<excpt.h>

int ExceptionHandler(void);
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

char temp[512];

printf("Application launched");

 try 
     {

    strcpy(temp,argv[1]);

    } catch ( ExceptionHandler() )
    {
    }
return 0;
}
int ExceptionHandler(void)
{
printf("Exception");
return 0;
}
```

I am compiling on Dev C++ 4.9.9.2. These are the errors I get

```
   Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Documents and Settings\madhur\Desktop\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Documents and Settings\madhur\Desktop\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c main.c -o main.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   
main.c: In function `int main(int, char**)':
main.c:20: error: `ExceptionHandler' is not a type
m    ain.c:20: error: invalid catch parameter
make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1
Execution terminated
```

Any idea what's so wrong with this code ?

Comment: No, the edit is not helping. `try/catch` doesn't catch the same kind of exceptions that `__try/__except` does. And the syntax is different.

Comment: Thanks , I will try Visual C++ compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ajay has pointed out SEH is a feature of the Microsoft C/C++ compiler. So there is little luck in using it with GCC (unless you use some addon support - see my comment at his answer about [libSEH](http://www.programmingunlimited.net/siteexec/content.cgi?page=libseh) - mind you I have not personally used it).

If there is no requirement to use GCC or Dev C++, you could try using the free [Microsoft Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) edition instead.

Answer (score 1):

`__try` and `__except` are Microsoft C/C++ specific keyword for SEH (Structured Exception Handling). You should use `try` and `catch` C++ exception handling.

Comment: +1: Just two things to add. SEH also works with C, C++ is not required. Second, there seems to be library (never used it) to emulate SEH for GCC: [libSEH](http://www.programmingunlimited.net/siteexec/content.cgi?page=libseh).

Comment: But there are no C++ exceptions involved in strcpy.

Comment: Thanks, I will try Visual C++ compiler

Comment: Yes, SEH would work for C also, C++ not required. I edited the post. No idea about GCC library, but yes, since it runs around SEH (RaiseException etc), there has to be some implemention in GCC too. 
@BoPersson: SEH would work for C also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `seh.h` for those things to be defined.